# Dimming (pulsing) lights in house can not find cause

Tags: electrical, wiring

For several years my lights have been dimming ,pulsing...not blinking but where you have to stare to see if its really doing it. Its in all rooms at times, like there is a huge draw somewhere in the service line. I have had Master electricians check it, couldn’t find it, wouldn’t charge me..and suspected the electric company Transformer on the service pole.

The Elec. Co. have found no leakage, and a few bare spots on wire to my Entrance meter box. They repaired but in 4 visits could not locate a problem that would cause this. We thought we found it several times, like a loose neutral, grounding or ground wire. Fixed or repaired with no difference. The main breaker on the service entrance pole was 50 years old and rusted. Mice and ground was not attached to anything anymore! Thought that was it for sure! Nope. Replaced the box and meter all circuits do it at times you can see it in lights.

Am I right in concluding its before the house panel? Most guess that when the transformer blows and NYSEG replaces it my problem will stop, NYSEG says it won’t replace what isn’t obviously bad even though its over 40 years old.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!   You may be chasing the wrong problem.  Put an AFCI breaker on that lighting circuit and see if it goes SNAP. This could also be a bad backstab connection

Answer (score 1):

Are there industrial plants within your area? I have seen problems on the main power feed from the utility caused by industrial equipment power factor balancing capacitor banks. I have also installed quite a few whole house surge protectors in that same area, the surges are easy to see with an Oscope but the power factor issue was tough until I rented a high end powermonitor that could detect the lead / lag issue. Both problems were caused by a plant several miles away, they were able to fix the problem with the cap banks as they had it set two sensitive and it was constantly hunting up and down causing some problems for home electronics in the area. The surge protectors were the only way to prevent damage to sensitive electronics because when huge electric motors start and stop they create dips and spikes on the line. Not sure if the power factor is causing your pulsing but it may be worth looking into.